# How do I pass in password to Pyramid and Cornice?

Tags: python, pyramid, cornice

I have a url like this:

```
http://site/account/login/
```

I want to do this through command-line, without form.

```
import requests
requests.get(url, auth=('username-goes-here', 'password-goes-here'))
```

But how do I design my views function in Pyrmaid using Cornice?

```
@user.get()
def login(request):
```

I don't see the `auth` tuple appears in `requests.GET` at all. I need to be able to get those parameters out...

Any idea?

Comment: just a guess, but requests probably puts those params in basic auth headers before sending the request, so on the pyramid side, check request.headers

Comment: The tutorial for cornice contains an example validator that shows how to validate requests...

Answer (score 4):

You can use HTTP headers to pass authentication token.
See http://cornice.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html